# Azure Function function.json file is missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I published my Azure Function, it run as expected. Then I updated the code a bit without changing any configurational value. Now my function.json file is missing in Azure and my function is not running...

[image]

[image]

I published with new profile. I was expecting to see function.json file.

Comment: @HariKrishna no, it needs to be read-only mode. my other functions are in read-only mode as well. Problem is function.json file(which is needed for running for functions) is missing.

Comment: Have you made any changes in function.json file after it's been generated?

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari no, I didn't make any changes. It was working fine after my first a couple of publishes. Then It stopped working.

Comment: Check if function.json file available or not in the kudu site of your function app

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari yes it is.

{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.1.3",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "runOnStartup": true,
      "schedule": "*/3 * * * *",
      "useMonitor": true,
      "name": "myTimer"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/GetCreditLimitData.dll",
  "entryPoint": "UES.CRM.Backend.GetCreditLimitData.GetCreditLimitData.Run"
}

Comment: I've been redeploying my functions and I'm able to see the function.json file. Could you check the [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20933) ticket which seems to be similar to your issue.

Comment: @PravallikaKothaveerannagari I checked it but it's for editing the function.json file. My case is azure portal does not show the function.json file for the function app I am publishing. That makes my app not running.

Comment: Could you check the function.json file is build/ compile-error free, check by redeploying/re-publishing.

Comment: As given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd#microsoftnetsdkfunctions), function.json file is generated by Function SDK Package. Check if that package reference is missing or up to date in `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad @*FurkanKaracan*, that you have resolved the issue by restarting the IDE and redeploying it.

- `Function.json` file missing issue will be caused if the function project is deployed with Runtime Issues.
- That file is generated by the Function SDK in `.csproj` file `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` NuGet Package.
- Any Changes to this file configuration code bindings are not allowed.

I have checked the following test cases to make the `function.json` file missing in the Code+Test menu:

1. Disabled the Function and redeployed from local IDE.
2. Published Several times by making function code changes through IDEs and CLI Commands.
3. Checked the Kudu Site of my Function App for every publish/deploy.

[image]
That file was visible perfectly how many times I redeploy the project to function app in the Azure Portal.

As per my experience, it might be some deployment issues while publishing.
Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4,cmd#microsoftnetsdkfunctions) for more info on `function.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting visual studio and redeploying the app fixed the issue. I really hate microsoft's technologies...